# Rotating image using matrix distorts the image when being saved

Tags: android, image, bitmap, camera, jpeg

I am implementing a custom camera in android. One of the phones that I am using the default display orientation is landscape mode. The preview of the image looks good when taking the picture. Nonetheless, when the immage is rotated and saved the image becomes distorted.

This is the code I am using to rotate the image:

```
    Display display = ((WindowManager) MyCamera.this.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();

    int rotation = display.getRotation();

    if (rotation == Surface.ROTATION_0) {
        rotation = 90;

    } else if (rotation == Surface.ROTATION_90) {
        rotation = 180;

    } else if (rotation == Surface.ROTATION_180) {
        rotation = 270;

    } else if (rotation == Surface.ROTATION_270) {
        rotation = 360;
    } 

    DisplayMetrics metrics = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
    Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inDither = false;
    options.inScaled = false;
    options.inDensity=metrics.densityDpi;
    options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;

    bm = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imgBytes, 0, imgBytes.length, options);

    Matrix m = new Matrix();
    m.postRotate(rotation);                 

    Bitmap nbm = Bitmap.createBitmap(bm, 0, 0, bm.getWidth(), bm.getHeight(), m, true);

    file = MyCamera.this.saveBitmap(nbm);
```

This is the code I'm using to save Bitmap image:

```
private File saveBitmap(Bitmap image) {

    File pictureFile = getOutputMediaFile(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE);

    if (pictureFile == null) {
        Log.d(TAG,"Error creating media file, check storage permissions: ");// e.getMessage());
        return null;
    } 

    try {



        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(pictureFile);
        image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fos);
        fos.close();

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "File not found: " + e.getMessage());
        finish();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Error accessing file: " + e.getMessage());
        finish();
    }  

    return pictureFile;

}
```

Here are some examples on how the image looks in camera preview mode and how it looks after it is saved on the phones external storage.

[image: camera preview]

[image: saved picture on phone]

Comment: The camera preview is after taking the picture. The saved photo screenshot is how the photo is stored on the phone.

Comment: I cannot tell what is being distorted because these look like two different images.

The top image has a light in the upper left corner that should be visible, but is not, in the bottom image.

Comment: They are two different images you are correct, but this is what happens all the time. For some reason I uploaded different ones, my mistake. However, you can see clearly that the second image is distorted.